# using json data instead of layer services url

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I did not want to use layers url in arcgis. Instead I want to use json data in arcgis can we do that?

```
var tileLayer = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/nzS0F0zdNLvs7nc8/arcgis/rest/services/US_Counties_basemap/MapServer ");
map.addLayer(tileLayer);

var layerUrl = "http://services.arcgis.com/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/arcgis/rest/services/USA_Counties_Generalized/FeatureServer/0";
```

Comment: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/data_requestJson.html